# Can raft guarantee correctness by not committing no-op logs?

Tags: distributed-system, raft

I have a question: the no-op operation is only mentioned in the raft paper in the optimization section of 8. However, there is mention of no-op logs to prevent "ghost recurrence", but this is not mentioned in the author's paper (poorly thought out?). So my question is, without read optimisation, i.e. without no-op either, can raft still be correct?

I am not sure if I have made my question clear.

I have read many articles but they say different things

update:
I am sorry that this question did not give as much contextual information as possible.
But I have found the answer so far, in short: no read optimizations, i.e. all read operations go into the log, and not committing the no-op log also ensures that the raft is e correct.

Comment: Hello,
Please your question isnt very clear, please provide more specific info about your problem. i am sure if you do that, others will be able to help you out with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what I'm talking about, so let's start with the conclusion that draft will still work correctly without read optimization and without committing the no-op.
The background of the "ghost recurrence" is that the read optimization is done without committing the no-op, so it appears.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).